# Kashiwara's definition of normal crystal

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quantum-groups, crystals

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a symmetrisable Kac-Moody algebra, and $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ its associated quantum group. Each integrable module of $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ admits a crystal basis, as was first shown by Kashiwara. In particular, the integrable irreducible module $V(\lambda)$ associated to each dominant weight has a crystal base $\mathcal{B}(\lambda)$.

On the other hand, we can define the notion of a $\mathfrak{g}$-crystal abstractly, as a set together with some partial operators satisfying some conditions (as in Section 1.5 of [this paper of Kashiwara's](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077288816)). There are *many* more $\mathfrak{g}$-crystals than those arising from integrable representations, so we can ask for necessary and sufficient conditions for a $\mathfrak{g}$-crystal to be isomorphic to a crystal arising from an integrable $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$-module.

> **Question 1**: Is there some characterisation of this kind of $\mathfrak{g}$-crystal, beyond that definition?

In that same paper of Kashiwara's, he defines a $\mathfrak{g}$-crystal $B$ to be *normal* if for every subset $J$ of the Dynkin diagram for which $\mathfrak{g}_J$ is finite-dimensional, the restriction $B_J$ is isomorphic to the crystal of an integrable $U_q(\mathfrak{g}_J)$-module. I cannot tell if this condition implies that $B$ is isomorphic to the crystal of an integrable $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$-module. I also cannot find this definition of normal appearing almost anywhere else in the literature, aside from [this other paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0202268) of Kashiwara's.

> **Question 2**: What kind of subset of $\mathfrak{g}$-crystals is Kashiwara's normal condition cutting out?

Comment: "We provide a simple list of axioms that characterize the crystal graphs of integrable highest weight modules for simply-laced quantum KacMoody algebras." Stembridge, A local characterization of simply-laced crystals. https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2003-355-12/S0002-9947-03-03042-3/

Comment: @SamHopkins For integrable highest-weight modules, there are the Stembridge axioms (for simply-laced type), and also the notion of a "closed family" in arbitrary type (due to Joseph, I think). I am asking about arbitrary integrable modules though, not just highest/lowest weight.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I missed that aspect.